# Is "browser" field of package.json useless？

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, package.json

I recently do some search about front-end project management and get a confusion.
I notice that there is a field **"browser"** in package.json, but I don't know what role it plays.
In my opinion, we use package pack tool like Rollup to build **.esm.js** for browser, and in browser, just import the .esm.js file by `<script>` tag, **we can't import any npm package in browser**. So, I think field "browser" is useless.
For example:
Project structure:

```
packageA---
         |--dist
             |--main.esm.js
             |--main.common.js
         |--main.js
         |--package.json
```

package.json:

```json
{
   "name": "packageA",
   "main": "./dist/main.common.js",
   "browser": "./dist/main.esm.js"
}
```

```js
// this is a js file which use packageA.
// when we use Node to execute this file, will return "./dist/main.common.js".
const p = require("packageA")
```

Q: in browser, how to import packageA ?  and who will follow the field "browser" and return "./dist/main.esm.js" to us?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When I don't know something - I [read the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#browser)

Comment: _"we can't import any npm package in browser"_ - there are many cases where you **can**.

Comment: documentation is not clear.

Comment: could you share a case ?@Dai

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you'd like to read [the specification of the `browser`
field of package.json](https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec).  *Npm* doesn't select platform-specific files directly, rather it's a **hint** to the **bundler** (such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/)) about which files to use depending on whether it's bundling for the browser or for something else (e.g.: for Node.js).

This way, the same code can be used between *node* and *browser* platforms.  When node *requires* the file, the default node-specific files are used, but when the bundler bundles it, the browser-specific files are used (substituted) instead.

-- That is hardly useless! --

Examples from the spec:

#### alternate main - basic

```
"browser": "./browser/specific/main.js"
```

#### replace specific files - advanced

```
"browser": {
    "module-a": "./shims/module-a.js",
    "./server/only.js": "./shims/client-only.js"
}
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you. I have figured out it! I associated the action of  `browser` field in browser env just with nodejs before, I never think about bundle.Your answer inspired me.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Wvck's answer, another typical setting for the browser setting has this, because `fs` module is a nodejs module. Then bundler won't pack `fs` module into the client code.

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false
  }
```